# I want to run Memgraph using WSL but I can't install Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, memgraphdb

In the [Memgraph official documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/install-memgraph-on-windows-wsl) it says "Install MemgraphDB using the latest Memgraph Ubuntu package and by running the following command in the Ubuntu terminal.". On the download page there are three Ubuntu versions, 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04. I've downloaded the right .deb file. From Memgraph part, everything works ok.

I get stuck when trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL. I don't see it. I have Windows 11 professional. Does this mean that Ubuntu 22.04 is perhaps not available in my Region?

```
PS C:\Users\Gai> wsl --list --online
The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed.
Install using 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>'.

NAME               FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu             Ubuntu
Debian             Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux         Kali Linux Rolling
SLES-12            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v12
SLES-15            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v15
Ubuntu-18.04       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04       Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
OracleLinux_8_5    Oracle Linux 8.5
OracleLinux_7_9    Oracle Linux 7.9
```

Comment: The distribution `Ubuntu` is in version 22.04. Distros without version numbers are always latest as possible. And if you look at it in MS Store, you will find that it states **"Ubuntu currently provides the 22.04.1 LTS release"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu 22.04 from the Microsoft Store.

[Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS on Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu-20045-lts/9MTTCL66CPXJ)

You can read more on the general availabilty of WSL in the Microsoft Store [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-in-the-microsoft-store-is-now-generally-available-on-windows-10-and-11/).

Comment: Is there a reason why it can't be installed via terminal?

Comment: @JulietteGia essentially, it decouples WSL from being a component of Windows and makes it easier to issue out-of-band updates.